# Haskell Array(Matrix) Element Access

Tags: arrays, haskell, matrix, element

I'm currently in a project that will need to access elements in an Array-Matrix in Haskell. So, I've tried googling it, searching everywhere.

The funcion is supposed to be like this:

```
getElementIndex :: Int -> Array (Int,Int) Int -> (Int,Int)
```

And it **must** return the `I` and `J` indexes of the element in the matrix.

Comment: So, given an element in a 2D array, you need to find that element (presumably, unique?) and return the indices you found it at? That's certainly possible (but a bit odd for arrays, since it will mean a linear scan). How far have you got so far?

Comment: Yes, it's unique.. I think I'll have to iterate through the whole array and check if the value is the expected and then if it is, return it. But I don't know how to access the elements (individually) in the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To read elements from `Array` types in Haskell, you use the `(!)` operator, as in:

```
Prelude Data.Array> let v = listArray (0,9) [1..10]
Prelude Data.Array> v ! 3
4
```

so, now all you need to do is walk the index space, rows and columns. I like list comprehensions for that kind of task:

```
assocs' x y arr = [ ((i,j), arr ! (i,j))
                  | i <- [0..x-1]
                  , j <- [0..y-1]
                  ]
```

which is just a specialized version of `Data.Array.assocs`:

```
assocs :: Ix i => Array i e -> [(i, e)]
```

which returns a lazy list of indices and elements. So, call `assocs`, and then take the first element that matches.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
\x -> map fst . filter ((==x) . snd) . assocs
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Matrixs in Preclude
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prelude_extensions#Matrices